# Android Gameloop Thread.join() hangs application

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, frame-rate

Hey all i am implementing the gameloop found here: http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/

My question is why does having:

```
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
```

In my surfaceDestroyed() function of my game view hang the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread.join()` will BLOCK until the thread you're joining completes. If that thread never completes, that function will never release.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot i had to break my while loop contained in the thread >.>

Answer (score 0):

Because `thread.join()` blocks the calling thread until thread is done.